# While running TestNG program in eclipse getting error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: automated-testing, testng, api-testing

Getting JNI error while running TestNG program (that doesn't have main() function).

[image]

But If trying to run the same program with same set of configuration (i.e. eclipse and java version), "Run as a java application" then it's working fine.

After click on OK button on the pop up of "JNI error", getting below error- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Java and javac versions are same.

```java
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

public class BasicsUsingTestNg {

    @Test
    public void Test1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

        given().param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362").param("radius", 500)
                .param("key", "AIzaSyB_mtr6ORifRUHaZIpTtppLfnSLshwObEc").

                when().get("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").

                then().assertThat().
statusCode(200).and().
contentType(ContentType.JSON).
and().body("results[0].geometry.location.lat", equalTo("-33.8688197"));
    }
}
```

If i am trying to run the same program with java main method, it's running successfully. Like below code-

```java
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

public class BasicsUsingTestNg {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

        given().param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362").param("radius", 500)
                .param("key", "AIzaSyB_mtr6ORifRUHaZIpTtppLfnSLshwObEc").

                when().get("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").

                then().assertThat().
statusCode(200).and().
contentType(ContentType.JSON).
and().body("results[0].geometry.location.lat", equalTo("-33.8688197"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112390/jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation

Comment: I have tried all the possible options mentioned in above link.
Inclusion of Jcommander jar also. But still facing the same problem. Because none of the solution worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the code here

Comment: I don't think so, that there is any problem in code. Because same is working perfectly fine with java main() function. When running the same program with "Run as Java application".
But getting error while running as TestNG test

Comment: *Getting JNI error while running TestNG program* - what does it mean? What steps are you taking exactly?

Comment: @Gaurav Which testng version you are using?

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff, i am using TestNG jar 7.1.0

Comment: @AlexeyR. JNI error shown in the screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796364/6793637

Comment: @PDHide, tried all the possible options suggested on above link, but didn't work for me

Comment: @Gaurav Please make a try with v 6.14.3

Comment: tried all of the above options suggested by you guys. Thanks for your answers. But unfortunately none of them could work for me. So finally i have to choose my project to get Mavenised, which i was avoiding earlier. But ultimately i had to choose the same.

Comment: We can close it now.